# Can anyone explain this isometry to me? $T: (\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_1)^*\to (\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$, $ T(x)(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Can anyone explain this isometry to me?
$$T: (\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_1)^*\to (\mathbb R^n,\|\cdot\|_{\infty}),\qquad  T(x)(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$$

I don't get what the domain and image of $T$ are.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know something about norm spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementing the very well detailed answer of Zev Chonoles, I think you've got it in the opposite direction. $T$ as is defined in the title is the mapping $x\mapsto T(x)=x^T$, such that $T(x)(y)=x^Ty$ is a linear transformation of the vector $y$. This means that the domain of $T$ is $(\mathbb R^n, \Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty)$ and its codomain is the dual space of linear transformations in $(\mathbb R^n, \Vert \cdot \Vert_1)$.

If you are wondering where the $1$ and $\infty$ came from or why the map is an isometry, you have to take a closer look at the norm of the space $(\mathbb R^n, \Vert \cdot \Vert_1)^*$. As Zev said, the norm of a linear transformation $ \ell$ of a vector $y\in (\mathbb R^n, \Vert\cdot \Vert_1)$ is
$$\Vert \ell \Vert= \sup_{\Vert y\Vert_1=1}|\ell(y)|.$$
This means that if $\ell$ is the image under $T$ of some vector $x$, then 
$$\Vert \ell \Vert=\Vert T(x) \Vert= \sup_{\Vert y\Vert_1=1}|T(x)(y)|= \sup_{\Vert y\Vert_1=1}|x^Ty|.$$
It turns out that the expression $\sup_{\Vert y\Vert_1=1}|x^Ty|$ is exactly equal to $\Vert x \Vert_\infty$! (You can try to prove this yourself, it's not so hard.) That is why the mapping is an isometry only when the domain is taken to be euclidean space *with the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ norm.*

One speaks of this phenomenon as $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$ norms being [dual of each other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm).

You can also try to prove the duality the other way round, that is $\sup_{\Vert y\Vert_\infty=1}|x^Ty|=\Vert x \Vert_1.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you're correct. How is that $T$ returns a number and not some vector in the dual space?

Comment: $T$ returns a function! You can evaluate it at the points $y$ to get numbers. (More precisely, it returns a linear function of points $y\in \mathbb R^n$)(Think of $x^T$ as a function of $y$, which evaluates to numbers and is linear as the "matrix product" is linear)

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, $T$ takes some vector $x$ and returns a function in the dual space. To show that T is an isometry all I have to do is show that $max{|x_i|} = sup|f(x)| s.t. |x| \leq 1$. Is this correct?

Comment: I added some remarks in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

A pair $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ denotes  a vector space $V$ over  $\mathbb{R}$, together with a norm function $\|\cdot\|:V\to\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ mean *"the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the $L^1$ norm"*, and *"the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the $L^\infty$ norm"*, respectively. You can take a look at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) for a discussion of $L^p$ norms.

When we have a normed vector space $(V,\|\cdot\|)$, its dual is defined to be the vector space$$V^*=\{\text{continuous linear functions }f:V\to\mathbb{R}\}$$
together with the norm function $\|f\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|=1}|f(x)|$.

The function $T$ is a continuous linear function from (the dual of ($\mathbb{R}^n$ under the $L^1$ norm)) to      ($\mathbb{R}^n$ under the $L^\infty$ norm).

Comment: In the action of $T$, there's an identification of $(\mathbb R^n,\Vert \cdot \Vert_1)^*$ with $\mathbb R^n$, which isn't covered by your answer (and which I find hard answering not knowing if the OP knows the Riesz representation theorem or a finite dimensional variant thereof.)